# Mixing Unity generated code with Objective-C in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to mix iOS code and interface elements with Unity generated iOS code?

For example if I am working with a game developer who is developing a game in Unity, could I take his xCode project (generated by Unity), and add interface elements which I code myself using Objective-C & Interface Builder etc?

From what I can see this isn't possible as everything is created via Unity.... but hopefully I am wrong...

Thanks!

Comment: Cal found this link http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/68320-Mixing-Unity-with-Objective-C?p=436556#post436556

Comment: It's not a easy work, I had writen a blog for this topic, and it's too long to post here. You can read it with google translate: [*Use iPhone Native UI in Unity3D*](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jtianling.com%2Farticles%2F2030.html) And the friends from china could read it directly [*在Unity3D中使用iPhone原生UI*](http://www.jtianling.com/articles/2030.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can even use 3rd party libraries in XCode and integrate them in the build process. After fiddling around with the right settings I wrote a blog entry about this:

[iPhone & Unity3D: Integrating 3rd Party Static Libraries in Unity3D Generated XCode Projects](https://www.scio.de/2011/08/iphone-a-unity3d-integrating-3rd-party-static-libraries-in-unity3d-generated-xcode-projects/?lang=en)

Comment: I had to take down my site for security reasons few days ago. I fixed the link by pointing to a previous version in the wayback machine at archive.org.

Comment: Can you just include it here instead, in case that happens again?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to generate Native plug ins to interact with the Unity code. You would need to write a wrapper though. Read more at: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html

Read the part at iOS :)

Comment: Which it actually did happen. There is no "iOS" part at that link.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this general guide to working with Unity native plugins in OSX which was useful and is probably where you need to be looking for your answer, as Zophiel said

https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/unity-native-plugins-os-x

Comment: Which it actually did happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can just design a view and button to trigger the unity to run or stop, but models in unity can't be controlled using Obj-C, although unity has import to Xcode, it only import the start code, game scripts depending on the link libraries which couldn't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it as the same way I probably has been working with Objective-C without any changes.  For Unity's code generator preserves the native codes under Classes.

And furthermore there is an another way to do this which is called "Plug-in".

But I hope the developers in Unity find a better way seamlessly combined with Xcode as staffs in Apple usually does.

Combining IB and Unity's integrated editor would be better and more welcomed in future.

Answer (score 0):

Possible yes. Advisable for beginner or intermediate level Devs? Probably not. The Unity project is generated and regenerated every time you push a build. Now I believe that if you use Append when you do builds that it should keep existing changes to the Xcode project... but 'should' is the operative word there. You may need to implement some sort of build system like Jeeves to keep the headaches to a minimum if you are trying to do this on a large project in which you for see a constant stream of updates from both the Unity side and the Xcode side.

Now if you're integrating code that is in it's own files and doesn't overlap or rewrite the code Unity has generated, then the Append feature is really going to work for you, but if you're deleting, altering, or adding code to any of the files that Unity generated then definitely use SVN or some other form of source control and snap shot before and after every new Unity recompile / Xcode generation.

Also, take a look in the Unity Asset store. Whatever functionality you are trying to home brew in Xcode can definitely be written in C# on Unity. Someone else may have already conquered the problem you're trying to solve and placed it in the asset store for $5.

Hope that helps.