# How to use an xcode game on unity3d

Tags: xcode4, unity-game-engine

I have a game built on xcode using objective c. this game needs to be integrated with another game developed in unity3d as a part of it. how can i do this? what plugins are available to achieve this??

The thing is that.. i have a unity3d game and i have few other games inside the main game(games inside one game). these small games are already built on xcode.. now i have to use these games inside the main unity game.. something like if i chose to play one of the games it has to load that particular xcode game.. how can i achieve this?? also if this is achieved.. can i build it on unity-android and expect it to work? or do i have to do it differently for android? Please guide..

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what you mean by "integrat[e]"? Is this meant to be a bundle, or a mini-game within a larger game, or?

Comment: @DuckMaaestro- A game is being built on unity3d in which i have to use a small already developed xcode game as a part of it.. a mini game (xcode game) within a larger game(unity game)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the following resources about mixing Unity3D code with Objective-C native code:

- [Mixing Unity generated code with Objective-C in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272413/mixing-unity-generated-code-with-objective-c-in-ios)
- [iPhone & Unity3D: Integrating 3rd Party Static Libraries in Unity3D Generated XCode Projects](http://www.scio.de/en/blog-a-neues/scio-development-blog/entry/iphone-a-unity3d-integrating-3rd-party-static-libraries-in-unity3d-generated-xcode-projects)
- [Unity Native Plugins: OS X](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/unity-native-plugins-os-x/#more-2824)

If both application modules need interact on a high frequency, I recommend a polling approach instead of SendMessage, because of a perfomance lack in the latter case.

Comment: So if it's what you are looking for mark it as accepted. If not but it's kind of useful vote it up. :-)

Comment: its is not completely what i was looking for, but this cleared a lot of things in my head.. i did vote it as useful :) :) thank you :) :)

Comment: "..vote it", the small triangle at the upper left corner of my answer (the upper one above the zero). After clicking the vote count will increase, like it did when I upvoted your question :-)

Comment: it says if i have to vote i need 15 reputations.. i have only 9 :( :( :(

Comment: Unfortunately, Clever Martian appears to have deleted his blog, but here is an archived version: http://web.archive.org/web/20120807041729/http://clevermartian.com/blog/?p=59