# Unity3D integration with UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, unity-game-engine

Please correct me if this question is duplicated.
I just came across Unity3D and I just want to ask if it is possible to integrate Unity3D on top of other UIView?

Comment: I have done that and create a repository with tutorial and downloadable project. I have write a answer here and downloadable project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714106/integrate-unity-app-to-existing-ios-app/40432425#40432425

Comment: You sort of can but GENERALLY SPEAKING ITS A TOTAL PAIN IN THE ASS, AND NOT WORTH IT.  I would honestly just forget about it.  Use Unity to make simple fun video games and leave it at that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's not possible that way because the generated AppController.mm acts as `UIApplicationDelegate`. And even if you manage to get it working, it sounds like you won't have fun on the long run. Major Unity3D updates might change some internals.

But the other way round i.e. calling Obj-C code from Unity3D and showing arbitrary UIViews is definitly working. See [How to use an xcode game on unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333120/437283) especially [Clever Martian's Blog - An Experiment with iPhone Native UI and Unity 3 Pro](http://clevermartian.com/blog/).

Comment: Unfortunately, Clever Martian appears to have deleted his blog, but here is an archived version: http://web.archive.org/web/20120807041729/http://clevermartian.com/blog/?p=59

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, but it's far easier to go the other way around.  Use Native Toolkit:

http://u3d.as/content/prime31/native-toolkit-unity-to-i-os-bridge/1vj

With this, you can bring up UIViews on top of your Unity3D app.  It works great and is very easy to use.  This is basically a plug and play version of what's described in the blog posts linked to in Kay's answer, I think.

Comment: Thanks for heads up. What I wanted to achieve is augmented reality games. In your way, is that possible to have a semi-transparent object on top of UIView? Thanks

Comment: No -- for Augmented Reality, use Qualcomm's ARSDK.  It's amazing and free.  Or, you can get the "Augmented Reality" plug-in from Prime31 which basically creates a texture that it copies the camera output to.  You can add code in the native plug-in to run any native iOS AR code over the frame that you want.  But it's a huge pain--use the Qualcomm AR SDK.

Comment: It looks like that plugin is no longer distributed or supported.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

This thread goes into detail:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-appcontroller-subclassing.191971/

One of the Unity developers even posts example code. Not how to specifically put Unity on a UIView, but how to encompass the Unity AppController to do ultimately whatever you want with it.

I have been maintaining hybrid Unity CocoaTouch apps for a few years. It used to be a complete hack. Now Unity has marginal support for it based on the things outlined in that thread. But it is a chore to keep it maintained. iOS and Unity slightly change every release, thus you must reintegrate unity into the iOS app a little different each release. Sometimes weird issues have come up that took me days to resolve. I personally, from experience, would avoid doing Unity and CocoaTouch hybrid apps for anything serious and highly predictable until they make it a bit more official. Ideally have official documentation about it in the manual. Not just have one of the developers posting code examples and the forum.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no Guide to manage this with the brand new Unity 5 (with IL2CPP Backend for 64 Bit) and Vuforia 4.x - i decided to write down my experience with it in a short tutorial.

http://www.makethegame.net/unity/add-unity3d-to-native-ios-app-with-unity-5-and-vuforia-4-x/

Hope it helps someone as it was a really bad task.