# Stop Threads in Unity3d using C#

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am doing an application in Unity 3d and integration with iPhone, i am doing some Image recognition task in unity and when user hit sharing button it loads iPhone native task, like load actionsheet and uialertview. When i present some model view controller then my app crash in iphone, i am doing this on main thread. I don't know where i am doing wrong, but i think if i'll stop some threads in unity it may help, or if you guys have any suggestion please help me. This will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping Unity threads doesn't sound like a good idea. It appears to me like there is something wrong in the way the native code is integrated. Maybe this question and the links inside can guide you through this task:

[Unity3D integration with UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336250/unity3d-integration-with-uiview)