# Any way to make bundle xcode project to include a static library xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, static

I have a static library xcode project (.a) and a bundle xcode project (.bundle)
I added the (.a) as a sub project of (.bundle) and added to [Target Dependencies] and [Link Binary With Libraries].

After run the bulid the (.bundle) still not contain any binary file inside (.bundle).

It's work if I add the .c and .h files to under (.bundle) directly, but that make me need to handle two project files. Any way can make (.bundle) just build with the (.a) ?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885569/how-to-organize-c-source-file-previously-compiled-by-gcc-make-and-build-them-int/9902919#9902919) same as what I asked, I tried to follow his 11 steps without the step 10 because he said lastly no need that step. But the generated (.bundle) still without contain any binary

Comment: Do you have a copy files build phase? What you really need here is to copy the library that is the product of the dependancy into the bundle.

Comment: @quellish thanks for your reply, I'm not targeting to just copy the .a to .bundle. I'm finding a way to make .a link and build a binary inside the .bundle

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish then - can you elaborate on why you're trying to build a binary inside the bundle, rather than copy a binary into it? Why is it unacceptable to build a target that produces a library, and then copy that library into the bundle that is the product of another target?

Comment: Because I need to create a (.bundle) Unity3D understand. just copy the  (.a) to (.bundle) Unity3D still will not understand. Anyways I figure out how it work and already put the answer below :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I make it work.

The step 10 still important and below is corrected step 10.

- create a dummy.c under (.bundle) project and the dummy.c can just totally empty. remove the  setting for the library you want to link inside `Link Binary With Libraries` instead use `-Wl,-force_load,$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/libYourLib.a` or `-all_load` to `Other Linker Flags`

PS: And also can use sub-project instead of workspace. and use `Target Dependencies` instead of `Edit Scheme` to achieve the same effect.

[The testing project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B35_CT-6Bau1bzRILUVPUExhRjg/edit?usp=sharing)