# iOS Plug ins for Unity

Tags: c#, ios, plugins, unity-game-engine

I know the basic premise for creating a plug ins for Unity is to create a wrapper for all the classes you want to call from within Unity. However, all of the docs and examples I have found have all expected a corresponding .cpp (if c++) or .mm (if objective-c) file.

However I'm trying to create a plug in for some native iOS code that doesn't contain any source files. All I have access to is four header files and a single .a file. [Which I have gotten from here.](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK)

Now, because I don't have any .mm files to wrap I'm a bit confused as to how I can go about bringing in these files into Unity so that I can call them from within. Has anyone ever done this before?

Can someone point me to some documentation, or anything that may help me, in bringing in 4 header files and .a file into Unity as a plug in?

Please remember, there are no source files that I have access to. Only the header files themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need source files, even the header files are not needed as long as you know the functions' declarations.

As described in [Building Plugins for iOS](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html):

1.) Put your .a file in Assets/Plugins/iOS

2.) Look at the header files to get the function signatures you need e.g.

```
void RegisterUnityIPodCallbackListener (const char* gameObject, const char* method);
```

3.) Declare `RegisterUnityIPodCallbackListener` within a C# class by:

```
public class IPodHandler {
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void RegisterUnityIPodCallbackListener (string gameObject, string method);
    public static void MyRegisterUnityIPodCallbackListener () {
       if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) {
           RegisterUnityIPodCallbackListener (GAME_OBJECT, METHOD);
       }
    }
}
```

4.) Call at an appropriate location:

```
IPodHandler.MyRegisterUnityIPodCallbackListener ("MyCallbackGameObject", "MyCallbackMethod");
```

**Common pitfalls:**

- You should not build directory structures within Assets/Plugins/iOS otherwise files don't get copied to the generated Xcode project
- Provide a fallback solution when testing in editor player

Answer (score 1):

Here is another guide: [How to build Unity3d Plugin for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834626/how-to-build-unity3d-plugin-for-ios)

A few notes if you get an error something like "Undefined symbols for architecture..."

1) Make sure the used architecture in .a-file matches yours (for example armv7)

2) Make sure the .a-file is compiled with libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library) since Unity requires that.

Comment: Is #2 really a requirement? I want to build a static library that uses various C++11 features, so I have been using libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support). 

I cannot get the final Unity XCode project to link though, and I cannot see a solution if #2 is true.

Answer (score 1):

The Estimote SDK you're are using has ObjectiveC classes. Functions in ObjectiveC can't be called directly via a Unity plugin (either can C++ classes for that matter). The reason is that function names are [managled when you compile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_Objective-C).

The interface between a Unity C# class and a library must a pure C interface. That is why there is often .mm or .cpp files along side a .a file. These are to wrap a C++ or ObjectiveC class in a pure C wrapper.

Your job is a little easier because most of the Estimote functions seem to be class functions. So you don't need to write wrapper functions to create and delete NSObjects.

Here is an example I wrote, a pure C wrapper around the TestFlightSDK. https://github.com/notoes/TestFlightUnity/blob/master/src/TestFlightCBinding.mm

Notice the extern "C" block, forcing the file the code to be compiled without name mangling. A c function signature and then an ObjectiveC call within the function.

So using the Esitmote [ESTBeacon class](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/blob/master/EstimoteSDK/Headers/ESTBeacon.h) as an example, the connectToBeacon call could like this:

```
extern "C" {
    void ESTBeacom_Connect()
    {
        [ESTBeacon connectToBeacon];
    }
}
```

And the .cs function would look like this:

```
class ESTBeacon {
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern void ESTBeacon_Connect();

    public static void Connect() {
        if( Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer )
            ESTBeacon_Connect()            
    }
}
```

Put the .cs, .mm and .a files in Plugins/iOS and you'll be all good.

Use this reference to find out how to pass various data types. http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries