# Unity get iOS photo library's video file

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

i need to get video file's path for unity engine

When i use ALAsset, it return only asset url like

```
assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=B650DDD2-32EC-45B6-A38C-537F4D1BDF53&ext=MOV
```

so i convert to NSData and writeToFile but this solution makes memoryWarning and too slow

there is no way to get file url like

```
file://~~~
```

EX) 'noon vr' app

PS. there is no way to get video from assets-library url in Unity?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(VideoObject)` to return the path of the gameobject asset in Unity Asset folder.

EDIT:
If you want to access the **iOS photo** or **video library**, you have to make a **plugin** for that in **Objective-C** then wrap it around with **C** and then **call** it from **C#(Unity)**

There is no need to re-write the steps. You can follow steps on **how** to **build plugins** for Unity here.

[How to build Unity3d Plugin for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834626/how-to-build-unity3d-plugin-for-ios)

Comment: i need to get path of non project video file
i think that is way to get path of video in project folder

Comment: When you mean non project file, you mean non Unity program file in iOS? What file are you trying to access and here is it saved...That may help explain things.

Comment: Video stored in the iOS's photo library , rather than the video assets stored in the project folder

Comment: Ok. Your question description is actually asking different stuff than what you just said. You can change your question description to be more undertandable. To answer that, you need to make a plugin for that in Objective-C then wrap it around with C++ and then call it from C#(Unity). Updated my answer with more info

Comment: generally writing a plugin for unity is nontrivial and there isn't always a swiss army knife tutorial - so it would have been more apropos if you linked something specifically with opening a video from the iOS photos library.  @Programmer

Comment: @ina I provided a link to the hardest part of doing this which is calling it from Unity. I assume that OP knows how to use Google to Google *"How to access iOS photo library"* and chose one of the many solutions out there then can use that as a plugin....

Comment: actually there are several complications with loading a video to unity movietexture from the iOS photo/video library

Comment: No one is talking about **movietexture** in both the question, answer or comment except you. OP simply needs to get the path of the photo/video folder. That's it. Nothing else was asked and I focused on what OP asked which **can** be done if he/she follow what's in my answer.