# Take a screenshot on ios for Unity/COCOS/SpritKit games

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, screenshot

- I want to develop an **IOS SDK** for **Unity/COCOS/SpritKit game** app to record video.Main program is to synthetic video after **screenshots**.
- Now I do the test  with IOS project from  unity game on  IOS 7.0 device  and  try to use **Opengl** function  **glreadpiexls**() to read pixel buffer, but always got the black image which troubled me   for weeks.  I try  some solutions like to set the context and set the EAGLView drawing property before glreadpiexls() but  not work.  And some suggest to make sure to  execute glreadpiexls() before  presentRenderbuffer, but how . I  can not modify the code  from Unity.
- Solutions like IOSuface depreciated on iOS 9.0 and seems only for UIView elements and IOSurface was depreciated on ios 9.0  and seems only for UIView elements.  RenderTexture or Application.CaptureScreenshot  are  only for unity project, not for my IOS SDK.

## So

So can anyone give me some suggestions for the screenshot  on iOS for Unity/COCOS/SpritKit games, and this is my current code.

```
int w = 320;//size.width;//viewport[2];//
int h = 480;//size.height;//viewport[3];//
NSInteger myDataLength = w * h * 4;    

// allocate array and read pixels into it.
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
```

> glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

```
GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
GLubyte temp = 0;
int index1 = 0;
int index2 = 0;
for(int y = 0; y < h - 1 - y; y++) {  // 交换
    index1 = y * 4 * w;
    index2 = (h -1 - y) * w * 4;
    for(int x = 0; x <w * 4; x++) {
        temp = buffer[index1 + x];
        buffer[index1 + x] = buffer[index2 + x];
        buffer[index2 + x] = temp;
    }
}

// make data provider with data.
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, myDataLength, NULL);


// prep the ingredients
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * w;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
// make the cgimage
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(w, h, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

// myImage is alway nil when debug
UIImage *myImage = [ UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:s orientation:UIImageOrientationUp ];    
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

> And some suggest to make sure to execute glreadpiexls() before
>   presentRenderbuffer, but how . I can not modify the code from Unity.

What they are saying is that you should convert that piece of code into a simple function. For example `void takeScreenShot(){//your code here}` then convert it into a plugin. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14885024/3785314) is how to do that.

After converting into a plugin, create a simple script in Unity and name it `UnityCam`. Attach this script to the main `Camera` in Unity. Inside the Unity cam script, call the `takeScreenShot()` that is in your iOS plugin. You should **ONLY** call it from the `OnPostRender()` callback function **not** from `Start()` or `Update()` function.

If that doesn't work, there is a new **hidden** and **undocumented** Unity API for recording Video on iOS. Download [Unity 5.4](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta) first, then use the code below to record video on iOS. Unity is working on recording for **Android** too but since this question is about **iOS**, the code below should do it. Note that it will only work on from **iOS 9** and above.

```
using UnityEngine.Apple.ReplayKit;

void startRecordingOnIOS()
{
    if (ReplayKit.APIAvailable)
    {
        if (ReplayKit.isRecording)
        {
            ReplayKit.StopRecording();
        }
        ReplayKit.StartRecording(true);//True to use mic, false not not use mic
    }
    else
    {
        //Fallback. Use your code from your question()
    }
}

void stopRecordingOnIOS()
{
    if (ReplayKit.APIAvailable)
    {
        if (ReplayKit.isRecording)
        {
            ReplayKit.StopRecording();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Fallback. Use your code from your question()
    }
}

void viewRecordedVideoOnIOS()
{
    if (ReplayKit.APIAvailable)
    {
        if (ReplayKit.recordingAvailable)
        {
            ReplayKit.Preview();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Fallback. Use your code from your question()
    }
}

void discardRecordedVideoOnIOS()
{
    if (ReplayKit.APIAvailable)
    {
        if (ReplayKit.isRecording)
        {
            ReplayKit.Discard();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Fallback. Use your code from your question()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yoour patients.When unity project  release to IOS, open it on XCode and add my recording sdk.And the fact is that, I can't modify the part of code from unity5 or cocos etc. I just want to do a general IOS SDK for  games which may be developed by engines  like unity3D  or cocos etc.

Comment: @JackMei It's really hard to understand your comment. If you are developing a recording API for Unity, my answer is enough to get you started. use the built in API from Unity. If it is not available on that device then use the plugin from your question. If you want anyone to be able to use your sdk in Unity, you have to to make it into a plugin so that they can all it from Unity side. You are getting a black screen because you are not calling that from the function `OnPostRender()` from unity. All these are mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer. I know it works but I need to develop a general ios sdk for unity/cocos/sprikit games.I am developing  a recording API on XCode not for unity. For game developers of my team， I will provide interface for the ios project from one of the three engines.So Can you understand what I mean？