# Open Gl or Unity?in iOS 3-D

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, opengl-es-2.0

I want  one 3-d object on my iphone. (not a game) I want it to be able to rotate like the Jenga app.  However heres the problem.  I want to put buttons on the 3-D object, so if I push it, it brings me to another View Controller or another screen. I have short experience in coding in xcode objective-C class however none in Open Gl or unity. Which should I study if I want to make this app? or is there something else? Is it possible to put a button on a 3-d object? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

best is learn unity3d its easy and more comfort for what you want to do. And also its cross platform tool so you can easily build apps for ios as well as android...and one thing you need unity licences for that.

Comment: Am I able to put buttons on the 3-D object? and and also use objective-C?

Comment: yes you can able to add buttons on 3-D objects ... and i am not sure about objective-C with unity ...unity support java script and c# language.

Comment: see this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272413/mixing-unity-generated-code-with-objective-c-in-ios)

Comment: It's free to publish to iOS and Android devices now using Unity. There's also the NinevehGL graphics engine for iOS: http://nineveh.gl/  it uses Objective C.

Comment: I want to put button on the 3-D object so that it will go to another view controller is that possible with NinevehGL.  What is that act called? putting button on the 3-d object is the main goal that i want to achieve.