# ios Unity 3d integration into native ios code

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have a native iOS code which is created in Xcode 5.1, Also I have one sample unity 3d ios project code.
I want to merge or integrate unity 3d ios code into my native ios code. How can I do that the same
Thanks In Advance

Comment: is this question about Unity3D plugins? If so, why it's upvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

Briefly:
Start first from simply one class let's say FooPlugin.cs in `Unity3D` which do the following:

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
private static extern float _FooPluginFunction();
```

which has public method:

```
public static void FooPluginFunction()
{
    _FooPluginFunction(); // call the native extension
}
```

Then build XCode project and add some FooPlugin.m which implements this method:

```
void FooPluginFunction() {
   // this is where native world is met
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks but suppose i just copied Unity ios code to my native ios code.. then it will work or not ?

Comment: i have unity 3d project (already converted to objective-c language for ios) and i want to used that project into my native ios project, so how can i do that ?

Comment: check this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272413/mixing-unity-generated-code-with-objective-c-in-ios